# How do you place a curve over a histogram with multiple factors?

Tags: r, curve, geom-bar

I think I am making this out to be much more complicated than it is, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I essentially have created a bar plot from some count data (vector counts), by day (vector day).  Within the plot I am factoring color by treat (vector treat).  What I would like to do is overlay some sort of curve instead of having the bars.  I am most interested in showing where the peaks are in the vector "counts" for each treat.

Here are the vectors within my dataframe, which I have named "data"

```
treat<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4)
counts<-c(9,12,11,5,3,2,0,2,0,0,1,1,0,10,4,7,6,1,4,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,12,5,15,3,4,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,4,6,11,7,7,4,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
day<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)

q=ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(day), y=counts, fill=factor(treat), color=factor(treat)))
q+geom_bar(stat= "identity", position=position_dodge(), width=.75)
```

Thank you for taking a look!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
data = data.frame(treat, counts, day)

ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(day), y=counts, group=factor(treat), color=factor(treat))) +
  geom_line(lwd=1) +
  geom_point()
```

The result is a bit hard to read for the these data, but maybe it will look better with your real data. Or you can use faceting, as shown by @Jaap.

[image]

Also, you can simplify your data creation as follows:

```
treat = rep(1:4, each=13)
day = rep(1:13, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show the peaks for `count` in each `treat`, then you might consider using facets with either `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid`. An example with `facet_wrap`:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(day), y=counts, color=factor(treat), group=factor(treat))) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~treat)
```

which gives you the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Oh I don't know why I didn't think of geom_line....a combination of working too long and thinking strictly of curves I'm sure.  But yes, I love facet wrapping and I think it shows the peaks nicely.  Thank you for your help!